# SQL Redundant NOT NULL Constraint

Tags: sql, constraints

When I'm adding some constraints, e.g:

```
 create table Test(
  IDTest int primary key,
  Credit int not null constraint Credit check (Credit >= 0)
 );
```

In this case isn't the `not null` in `Credit` redundant as I'm adding a constraint that `Credit` must be higher than 0?

Comment: Notice: some (MySQL...) SQL engines silently ignore the `CHECK` constraint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not redundant.

A `CHECK` constraint accepts a value if the condition is not `FALSE`, so whether it is `TRUE` or `UNKNOWN`.

If you allow Nulls in your column, then a `NULL >= 0` will evaluate to `UNKNOWN` and will pass the test.

Comment: Thank you, makes all the sense :)

Comment: @RSort: Consider the alternative: if it were a requirement that the condition had to be TRUE then every constraint involving nullable columns would have to explicitly test for nulls and that would be a lot of noise and pain!